# Is my proof of a generalized Hurwitz's theorem correct?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the following:

> Let $f_n(z)$ be a sequence of functions which are analytic in a region $\Omega$. Suppose that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$, and that the $f_n$'s have at most $m$ zeros in $\Omega$. then $f(z)$ is either identically zero or has at most $m$ zeros.

Here is my attempt:

Suppose that $f$ is not identically zero, yet it has $m+1$ zeros $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_m,z_{m+1}$. We can join the points by a polygon $\Gamma:z_1 \to z_2 \to \dots \to z_m \to z_{m+1} \to z_1$ which is contained entirely in $\Omega$ since it is open. $\Gamma$ is compact, while $\partial \Omega$ is closed, so the distance $\delta=dist(\Gamma,\partial \Omega)$ is strictly postive. Consider now "thickenings" of $\Gamma$ of widths $<\delta$, $U_\varepsilon:= \{z:d(z,\Gamma) \leq \varepsilon \} $. There must exist some $\varepsilon_0 \in (0,\delta)$ such that $f$ has no zeros on $\partial U_{\varepsilon_0}$. Using the locally uniform convergence and Weierstrass' theorem we see that $\frac{f_n'}{f_n} \to \frac{f'}{f}$ uniformly on $\partial U_{\varepsilon_0}$. Thus we have $$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\partial U_{\varepsilon_0}} \frac{f_n'(z)}{f_n(z)} \mathrm{d} z \to \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\partial U_{\varepsilon_0}} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \mathrm{d} z $$  But this is impossible since all of the numbers on the left are $\leq m$, yet their limit is $\geq m+1$ (I applied the Argument Principle here).

Is this OK?

Comment: If your definition of region includes connectedness (I think the usual term for that would be "domain") - the result is evidently false for disconnected open sets, and the polygon $\Gamma$ would not in general exist then. You have a typo in "we see that ... uniformly on ...", the limit has no indices, it's $\frac{f'}{f}$. Apart from that, it looks fine. You could argue with small open disks around the $z_i$, for all sufficiently large $n$, $f_n$ must have a zero in each of the (disjoint!) disks [can also be deduced from the minimum modulus principle].

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks!

Comment: In case your region is multiply connected. .